# Configure postfix to temporary reject all incoming email with a 451

Tags: postfix

I need to configure a Postfix server to temporary reject all (SMTP) incoming email with a "451 Try again later"

Any ideas?

Regards

Ian

Comment: I'm not sure that's an optimal solution to any problem. Why are you trying to do this? http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378

Comment: I'm trying to configure a postfix server to act as a FakeMX server, therefore reject emails with 451 message for those supported domains and still reject other domains with relaying denied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

postconf | grep reject lists a number of configuration directives containing reject.

I´d probably just set

```
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 451
unknown_virtual_alias_reject_code = 451
unknown_virtual_mailbox_reject_code = 451
```

and remove the domains in question from `mydestination` and `virtual_mailbox_domains`.

So basically tell postfix to not accept mail and to reject it using 451s.

Comment: Hi 

Thanks for your reply.  Nearly there…  

I need to configure postfix to reject all emails for the domains it looks after with a 451 message but still rejects any other domains with a relay denied message. 

Any ideas?